# Equivalence Testing for Absolute Mean Difference

Tags: mean, equivalence, tost

I have a paired dataset: for each sample $x_i$ I have calculated $\theta^A_i, \theta^B_i$ using models A,B. Let $\xi_i=\theta^A_i - \theta^B_i$ and assuming equal-sized equivalence boundaries $\epsilon_U=\delta, \epsilon_L=-\delta$, a TOST should be in the form (according to [Lakens 2017](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1948550617697177)):

$$t_L=\frac{\bar{\xi}+\delta}{\sqrt{Var(\xi)/n}}, \qquad t_U=\frac{\bar{\xi}-\delta}{\sqrt{Var(\xi)/n}}$$

and the TOST itself is (reject the inequivalence hull hypothesis if):

$$t_U \leq -t_{n-1, \alpha} \text{  and  } t_L \geq t_{n-1, \alpha}$$

with $t_{n-1, \alpha}$ being the upper $\alpha$ percentile ([Berger & Hsu 1996](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-11/issue-4/Bioequivalence-trials-intersection-union-tests-and-equivalence-confidence-sets/10.1214/ss/1032280304.full)). That is, if $\alpha=0.05$ we take $t_{n-1, 1-\alpha}$. Up to here, it's all in literature.

Now, assuming that I want to test for $\zeta_i=|\xi_i|$: instead of two one sided tests I only have one, with the test statistic

$$T=\frac{\bar{\zeta}-\delta}{\sqrt{Var(\zeta)/n}}$$

In such case, should the rejection be when $T\leq t_{n-1, 1-\alpha}$, or when $T\leq t_{n-1, \alpha}$? The former is more loyal to the literature but quite lenient, and the latter is less loyal but stricter.

Which should I use?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation. Let's assume $\hat{\theta}$ denotes an estimator of $\theta$. Do you want to use a test statistic of the form $T=(|\hat{\theta}-\theta_0|-\delta)/\sqrt{\hat{\mathbb{V}}(\hat{\theta})}$ to test $H_0:|\theta-\theta_0| \geq \delta$ vs. $H_1:|\theta-\theta_0| < \delta$, where $|\hat{\theta}|=\bar{\zeta}$ and $\theta_0=0$ in your case? If so, calculating the *p*-value based on the *lower*-tail probability or rejecting based on the corresponding $\alpha$-quantile would be equivalent to the TOST procedure. I could elaborate on that in an answer if needed.